# PDFMake Removing border around pdf

Tags: jquery, html2canvas, pdfmake

Am generating pdf by using pdfmake. PDF generating properly the problem here is it is generating border around the content. i tried to remove them by using layout"'noBorders' and other ways also. but no luck , can anyone sort out this issue. here is my code sample

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('div2'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas2) {
        var data2 = canvas2.toDataURL();
        var docDefinition2 = {
            content: [{  
                layout: 'noBorders',
                image: data2, alignment: 'center',
                fit: [700, 700], margin: [40, 0, 0, 0], 
                pageBreak: 'after'
            }]
        };                         
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition2).download('batch5df885f0-6e16-453e-83cb-b09d2e990bad.pdf');    
    }
});
```

Comment: border seems like it's the image borders than the pdf doc border.  Got screenshot?

Comment: You have no borders in docDefinition, probably border is from canvas. Remove border in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0`; to the `body` tag in your css, and `display: block;` to the canvas tag in your css.

**Example:**

```
canvas {
        display:block;
    }

body {
    margin:0;
}
```